# Can't get screenx property for DIV in AutoIT

Tags: html, internet-explorer, click, autoit

I'm trying to get the screen coordinates for a DIV with id=1862 in order to click it in AutoIT. Here is how I'm able to view the text inside the DIV so that I know it can detect it:

```
local $element=_IEGetObjById($oIE, "ember1862")
_IEFormElementSetValue($element, "Eric")
```

It successfully resets the value in the search box.

But when I attempt to click it with:

```
_IEAction($element, "click")
```

or

```
$element.click
```

It does nothing.

When I try to get the coordinates it always tells me that they are all 0 which I know is not true (its sitting the middle of the page):

```
local $search = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "ember1862")
MsgBox(0,"",_IEPropertyGet($search,"screenx"))
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but this function worked---

Function to get the coordinates:

```
func _IEfindPosX($o_object)
    local $curleft = 0
    local $parent = $o_object
    if IsObj($parent) then
        while IsObj($parent)
            $curleft += $Parent.offsetLeft
            $parent = $Parent.offsetParent
        wend
    else
        local $objx = $o_object.x
        if IsObj($objx) then $curleft += $objx
    EndIf
    return $curleft
EndFunc
```

Looping through all html inputs to get the x coordinate:

```
$oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection ($oIE, "input")
For $oInput In $oInputs
    MsgBox(0,"",$oInput.id)
    MsgBox(0,"",_IEfindPosX($oInput))
Next
```